# Alter specific text to string as a key in JSON

Tags: notepad++, javascript, json

I'm trying to convert numbers as shown in figure below to a JSON key with value in an object. Please can someone help me with that? The image below shows what I'm trying to do in notepad++.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Use **search and replace** in notepad++ with de regular expresion option tilded

- search for `\b(\d+),\{`
- replace with `"\1":{`

It isn't pefect, but works